# Representing a text file into a list using python

Tags: python, list, text, line, python-3.6

I want to open a text file in a list using Python.

The structure of my `text.txt` file is as follows:

> "Sentence 1.", "Sentence 2.",..., "Sentence n."

Each sentence is embedded with punctuation marks and separated by comma mark. I want to print it in a list maintaining same structure.

I want the output to be displayed as:

```
["Sentence 1.", "Sentence 2.",..., "Sentence n."]
```

But as of now, I am getting the output in the below mentioned format

```
['"Sentence 1.", "Sentence 2.",..., "Sentence n."']
```

How to exclude the extra single inverted punctuation mark? Any help is appreciated.

This is my code:

```
def read_data():
    global new_list
    with open("text.txt", 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
       raw_data = f.read()
       new_list = [raw_data.strip()]
       print(new_list)
read_data()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `text.txt` file is basically a csv file. Using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html) module we can do the following:

```
import csv

with open("text.txt", 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
    new_list = next(reader)
```

Comment: Yes. Its a text file generated from a csv file. Thank you it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def read_data():
    with open("text.txt", 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
       raw_data = f.read()
       new_list = [i.replace('"', '').strip() for i in raw_data.split(',')]
       print(new_list)

read_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use split function ?

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

def read_data():
    global new_list
    with open("text.txt", 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
       raw_data = f.read()
       new_list = raw_data.split(",")
       print(new_list)


read_data()
```

This will print out:

```sh
["Sentence 1.", "Sentence 2.",..., "Sentence n."]
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried using `split`, but it won't help me to solve the issue.

Comment: `.split` is prone to some nasty edge cases: `'"Sentence, 1", "Sentence, 2."'`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you properly, you actually want a list. However, in your code you have a list of one element (one string), for that reason you see an extra punctuation mark...
I think you want the following:

```
def read_data():
    global new_list
    with open("text.txt", 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        raw_data = f.read()
        new_list = raw_data.strip().replace('"','').split(',')
        print(new_list)
read_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function

You can pass the text from your file to the `eval()` function that will convert into a list.

```
lis = eval(open('file_name').read())
```